# How to print two strings on the same line in c

Tags: c, string

I want to input a string with spaces and print that string with a another string on the same line.

```
int i = 4;
double d = 4.0;
char s[] = "Apple ";
int x;
double y;
char z[105];

scanf("%d",&x);
scanf("%lf",&y);
scanf("%[^105\n]s",z);

printf("%d\n",i+x);
printf("%0.1lf\n",d+y);
printf("%s %s",s,z);
return 0;
```

Comment: `%[^105]` will consume all characters, (including the `'\n'`) for input NOT containing a `1, 0 or 5` until an `'s'` is found or end-of-input is reached. It appears you intended `"%104s"` as your format string.

Comment: i'm sorry. that's a mistake.

Comment: should be Apple

Comment: Correction, you intended to use `"%104[^\n]"`

Comment: actually i'm not inputting exactly 104 characters

Answer (score 2):

You `scanf` *format specifier* `"%[^105]s"` uses a *character class* `[...]` which is a stand-alone specifier in and of itself and does not requires `'s'` at the end. By placing `'s'` at the end you are forcing `scanf` to look for a literal `'s'` following an unlimited number of characters NOT including `1, 0, 5`.

It appears you intended to use the number to protect your arrays bounds -- which is a good thing, but the proper format in that case is `"%104[^\n]"` which will read up to `104` characters that do not include a `'\n'` (preserving space for the *nul-character*).

For example:

```
    if (scanf("%104[^\n]",z) == 1)
        printf("%s %s\n",s,z);
```

(**note:** ALWAYS validate ALL user-input by at minimum checking the return)

**Also note:** by NOT reading the `'\n'` above, it is left in your input buffer (`stdin`) unread, and if your next attempted input is `"%c"` or `"%[...]"`, you will take the `'\n'` as part of your input as nether `"%c"` or `"%[...]" consume leading whitespace.

Putting it together in an example you could do:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {
    char s[] = "Apple";
    char z[105];

    printf ("enter z: ");
    if (scanf("%104[^\n]",z) == 1)
        printf("%s %s\n",s,z);
    else
        fputs ("error: stream error or user canceled.\n", stderr);

    return 0;
}
```

(**note:** instead of `scanf` for reading lines, `fgets()` is recommended, then simply trim the `'\n'` included in the filled buffer)

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/oneline
enter z: is a fruit
Apple is a fruit
```

**Use `fgets()` Instead**

Instead of using `scanf` for line input, use a *line-oriented* input function like `fgets()` which will consume an entire line (including the line ending). The ensures your input buffer is left in a consistent state that does not depend on the previous format specifier user, e.g.

```
...
#include <string.h>
...
    printf ("enter z: ");
    if (fgets (z, sizeof z, stdin) != NULL) {
        z[strcspn (z, "\n")] = 0;               /* trim '\n' from end of z */
        printf("%s %s\n",s,z);
    }
```

**Edit Per-Question in Comment**

Your **Problem With Your New Code Is** `scanf("%lf",&y);` leaves the `'\n'` in `stdin` **unread**, you then attempt to read `scanf("%[^105\n]",z);` which reads **nothing** because you have excluded reading `'\n'` in the *inverted character class* and you then read `stdin` as input where the **first character** is `'\n'`. `"%[^105\n]"` means : read an unlimited number of characters and only stop the read if a `1, 0, 5` or `'\n'` character (or `EOF`) is encountered.

Taking *mixed* input with `scanf` is full of **Pitfalls** for new C programmers because of what is left in `stdin`, and how leading *whitespace* is handled depends on the *format-specifier* used. This is why `fgets()` (or POSIX `getline()`) are recommended for user input, and then parsing the needed information from the filled buffer with `sscanf`. With a *line-oriented* input function, the line is completely consumed on each input (given a sufficient buffer size -- don't skimp), eliminating the problems with `scanf`.

To make your current code work, you could do:

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* simple function to empty remainder of line in stdin */
void empty_stdin (void)
{
    int c = getchar();

    while (c != '\n' && c != EOF)
        c = getchar();
}

int main (void) {

    int i = 4, x; 
    double d = 4.0, y; 
    char s[] = "Apple ", z[105];

    scanf("%d",&x);
    scanf("%lf",&y);        /* leaves '\n' as next char in stdin */
    empty_stdin();          /* empty extraneous characters */
    scanf("%104[^\n]",z);   /* read up to 104 chars, \n, or EOF */

    printf("%d\n",i+x);
    printf("%0.1lf\n",d+y);
    printf("%s %s\n",s,z);

    return 0;
}
```

(**validate** each call to `scanf` -- that is left to you)

Let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Interesting order of `fputs`

Comment: How so? The stream goes at the end with `fputs`, unlike `fprintf` where it goes at the front.

Comment: Yes, I find it weird

Comment: I'm sure it hearkens back to a time before standardization when the C developers just put things where they made sense to them. The `fgets/fputs` functions stuck the stream parameter at the end, while whoever worked on the variadic `fprintf` liked it at the beginning -- and now we are just stuck with it `:)` Generally, as a rule, unless there is a conversion required, `puts` (or `fputs` if you need line ending control) is proper. (I should have used `fputs ("enter z: ", stdout);`) instead of `printf` -- but a good compiler will actually optimize and replace with `fputs` in that case)

Comment: when i write code as     char s[] = "Apple ";
    char z[105];
    scanf("%[^105\n]s",z);
    printf("%s %s",s,z);
    return 0;

Comment: i get the intended result

Comment: but when i added other code lines in my question it doesn't work

Comment: You get the intended result with `char z[105]; scanf("%[^105\n]s",z);` because you are reading the entire input into `z` including the newline and whatever is on the next line (and the next -- everything that does NOT include a `1, 0` or `5`) until `EOF`. If you edit and show me your exact input and output I can explain further exactly where the problem is.

Comment: #include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int i = 4;
    double d = 4.0;
    char s[] = "Apple ";
    int x;
    double y;
    char z[105];

    scanf("%d",&x);
    scanf("%lf",&y);
    scanf("%[^105\n]",z);

    printf("%d\n",i+x);
    printf("%0.1lf\n",d+y);
    printf("%s %s",s,z);
    return 0;
}

Comment: i only get to input 4 and 4.0

Comment: then i get 8 and 8.0 and Apple  81/4

Comment: i can't input the string

Comment: Let me look at it and I'll add to the answer. Also, do not *Change* your question. Instead add new information *Below* your original post. That ensures the original comments and answers continue to make sense.

Comment: @DasunAroshana Please remember that details *matter* when coding. `%[^105\n]s` is a completely different format specifier than the correct `%104[^\n]`. As clearly stated in this answer, the number immediately after the `%` means "read up to 104 chars" and the `[^\n]` , "not including a newline". The extraction will stop either when all the 104 are read or when a newline is found in the stream. You'll find more details in your textbook.

Comment: **Your Problem Is** `scanf("%lf",&y);` leaves the `'\n'` in `stdin` **unread**, you then attempt to read `scanf("%[^105\n]",z);` which reads **nothing** because you have excluded reading `'\n'` in the *inverted character class* and you then pass `stdin` as input where the first character is `'\n'`. `"%[^105\n]"` means : read an unlimited number of characters and only stop the read if a `1, 0, 5` or `'\n'` character (or `EOF`) is encountered.

Comment: i can understand the problem

Comment: I showed you. Look at the `empty_stdin()` function I included in the second version. Use that between each call where you need to empty any extraneous characters from `stdin`. You also need to check the return of `scanf` each time to handle (1) a manual `EOF`; (2) a *matching* or *input* failure, or finally (3) return equals the number of conversions specified indicating good input. See [scanf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html)

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by using \n in scanf(**"%lf\n**",&y);